# Any website with multi-level PHP tests?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this can be asked here, as it's not directly related to a piece of code.

I'm starting to learn PHP and I'm wondering if there's any websites that have multi-level tests (e.g. beginner/intermediate/advanced) or multi-subject tests (e.g. operators/variables etc).

I just had a go at the w3schools one and hit 95% which isn't too bad, baring in mind it's extremely simplistic, but I'd like a place to test my knowledge in a systematic way, that way when I answer a question incorrectly, I can refer back to sources and focus on those particular weak points.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.spoj.pl/HSPLARCH/problems/third/

Barely related to websites(PHP) though

Answer (score 1):

If you won't mind paying for this, there is the Zend PHP Certification programme. Without getting into the certification programme you can buy the PDF study guides which have sample questions from the actual exams. 
I don't really know any free resources, sorry :)

http://shop.zend.com/en/php-certification/php5-certification-training.html

PS: Yes, I know, the price is steeeeeeeep, at least for me!

Comment: +1 Zend is the company behind PHP, so their certification has backing in the eyes of potential employers (if that's what you're after)